# Product Attribute images Error

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have a problem with a magento website.
please check [https://onlybrands.me]
When I go to any prduct with size attribute I got like this [https://imgur.com/xPEpMRB][1]
Any Ideas?
Thanks

[1]: MAgento Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have used porto theme. Your images not showing because image path not getting for your size attribute. I think there should be some setting in porto theme or in your product attribute there are option for add attribute option images. Also you can check with enable template path hints and check phtml file for swatches. Thanks.